# Why are my app settings not appearing in the Settings app?

Tags: iphone, settings, ios, beta-seed-program

I cannot seem to find my app settings in the setting app after updating my [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) to iOS 10.3 beta 4 (14E5260b).

[image]

The issue is still present even after waiting a night, so it's not an issue about apps taking a long time to load.

Were they moved or **removed**? If they were moved, can you tell me where I could now find them?

Comment: Could be a bug. I'm on the same beta with no problems. Maybe try force restarting the phone - if that doesn't work, file a bug report using the Feedback app

Comment: It also takes my phone, as always, several seconds to a minute to register all the apps. I have always had this problem and this beta version hasn't really helped my phone with issues like these

Comment: @Jackson1442 Night has passed for me and the apps are still not there. I'm going to try to test out the other person's suggestion.

Comment: @NoahL I'm going to try a hard reset; can you make that into an answer so I can accept it if it works?

Comment: I swept closed all the apps on my phone immediately after opening settings (closing it too) and they came back - so far I have closed and reopened 4 times. Couldn't view them twice in a row ever since yesterday. Hard boot did NOT close the apps. They were still open after the restart. Apple support could not even help me. I found this by accident

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I experienced this issue for the first time this morning, on iOS 10.3. To fix, I simply opened multitasking view (double-click **Home**), and ejected the **Settings** app. Upon reopening it, app settings returned beneath *TV Provider*.

I’m quite surprised at the number of bugs with the **Settings** app since iOS 10 (another would be the disappearing navigation arrow in the upper-left).

Comment: My applications disappear all the time from settings and I always do the *close settings application from tasks* to get them back. iPhone SE, iOS 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

I am a iOS developer, and I just ran into this in an app I'm building.

From what I can tell, the application is only added to the setting app if

1. The app developer adds an additional set of files to the app called the settings.bundle which ops into listing the app in the settings app. If the developer has done this the app will be added to your settings app, when the app is installed on your device.
2. Or if the user grants the application permissions that are listed under app settings (this includes things like location permissions, or notification permissions). In this case the app will not be listed in the settings app until one of these permissions is granted by the user.

By default the app will not be listed in the settings app by default. If you want to have it added to your settings app, try granting it permissions to send you push notification, or access your location.

There is an issue where, if you've denied the app permission to use these features, the app may not be able to ask you to give it permission again, and you will not be able to access it's permissions via the settings app to grant the app permission to use these features. In this case you will need to delete the app from your device and re install it in order for the app to be able to ask you to grant it permission.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in iOS and quite an old one at that. It may be caused by an app providing bad settings metadata, but I haven't yet found the true cause. I've seen two solutions work.

Your best bet is to try just killing and reopening the Settings app. I've seen this work on at least a few occasions so it should be your first attempt. However, if that fails you, another solution that I've seen work is to go into Settings->General->Reset and choose Reset All Settings.

However, be warned, you'll lose literally all your settings, including passcodes, fingerprints, wi-fi connections, device name, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to uninstall/reinstall one app. It was then that all installed apps reappeared in Settings.

Comment: Why would *anyone* want to have to reinstall an app almost every reboot?!

Answer (score 0):

Kill all te apps. Click the home button twice and swipe all the apps stored on your screen until they are all gone. Only your home screen should be showing.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Can you add more details to your answer to address, specifically, how this will resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some of my apps but not all of them were showing in settings. In Settings ->Notifications, I was missing my Class Dojo app entirely.  I was not receiving instant messages from my son's teacher but couldn't change the settings. Some online answers recommended uninstalling/reinstalling the entire SETTINGS app, but I didn't want to reset ALL my passwords etc.  (I just did that a few weeks ago when I had to get a new phone after speaker wasn't working. In fact, that's when I started having problems). I just un/reinstalled the one affected app and that seemed to work. I may find others affected later, but so far it seems to have just been that one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this (July 2022) while trying to debug an issue with one of our apps on older devices and older iOS versions. On an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.3.3 the rows of non-Apple apps ("Twitter", "Facebook", etc.) stops after the app "TV Provider".

I deleted all of our own apps from the device, restarted the device, and looked again. ALL the third-party apps now appeared as expected, but within a few seconds they DISAPPEARED again, back to the list stopping at "TV Provider".

My suspicion is "TV Provider" (an Apple app) is the culprit, somehow breaking the process of listing these third-party, non-Apple apps. And when the issue is 'fixed' by other means, "TV Provider" recreates the problem.

I have no advice beyond this observation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the app.  It will ask for permission to use something.  That ask will push it onto the Settings app.

Answer (score -1):

I recently had this issue. It affected all OS on our side including iOS 15.
I found something that fixes it. In `info.plist`, add the key **Localizations** and add an item. I added French because our app is a French app. This will add your app settings to your device settings.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode .plist file showing the addition of Localizations item French]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).